# Longitudinal data modeling with lmer

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, panel-data

In a longitudinal dataset, each subject is tested every x period of time. I need to find the correlation coefficients between the score, age, and experience in years.
The age and experience increase with the time variable (time = (t1, t2, t3))

I tried solving for

```
fit1<-lmer(score~age_baseline+experiance_baseline+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
fit2<-lmer(score~age+experiance+time+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
fit2<-lmer(score~age+experiance+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
```

I am interested in finding the yearly change rate of age and experience... I got a bit lost with the options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fit1<-lmer(score~age_baseline+experiance_baseline+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
```

This model does not have time, thus it assumes there is no systematic time effect on `score`. This might be a baseline model you use to compare against more complex models with time.

```
fit2<-lmer(score~age+experiance+time+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
```

This model adds time and assumes that the time effect is the same across all subjects. I am not clear why the age and experience variables here do not have `_baseline` in them. What is the difference?

```
fit3<-lmer(score~age+experiance+(1|subject),REML = F, data)
```

This is the same as the first model (I've renamed it to `fit3`), again without `_baseline`.

If you want to allow the effect of time on `score` to vary across persons, then you want to use the second model and add in a varying (random) slope for time, as such:

```
fit4 <- lmer(score ~ age + experiance + time + (1+time|subject), REML=F, data)
```

You can assess whether this model fits your data better than `fit2`, which forced the time effect to be the same for all subjects. The `anova` function in R will do this for you: `anova(fit2, fit4)`. If the $\chi^2$ test is significant, then `fit4` provides a better fit to your data and is the model you want to use to assess the effects of `age` and `experiance` on `score`.

Comment: Thank you, @Erik Ruzek. 
Just to note- the difference between age_baseline and age is that age_baseline is constat in all measurements per subject and doesn't advance by time (exp: 23, 23, 23). Whereas age advances with time (exp: 23, 23.5, 24). Same for the experience... is your answer remains the same?

Comment: *Also, I tested the (1+time|subject) option but it results in "boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular"

Comment: -perhaps because time is (0, 0.5, 1)?

Comment: I see. In that case, I would keep `age_baseline` and `time` in the model. Do not include `age`. Try `fit1a <- lmer(score~age_baseline+experiance_baseline+time+(1|subject)...)` and then run `fit1b` with `(time|subject)`. The coding of `time` is not a problem, although you could still get a problem with fit due to there being no heterogeneity in time effects across subjects.